# JSHint for SublimeText2 doesn't find node.js path even if it's right

Tags: node.js, path, sublimetext2, jshint

I've installed `JsHint Gutter` package in my SublimeText 2, but when I'm try to use it SublimeText give me this error:

> Node.js was not found in the default path. Please specify the location.

The path on the preference file is right.If I try to type it in my console it works fine.
This is the line of the pref. file where the path is set.

```
    "node_path": "/usr/local/bin/node"
```

This is the versions info:

- MacOS X 10.9
- Sublime Text 2.0.2
- node.js v0.10.22

Comment: What's the exact name of the package? I don't think there's a package called just "JSHint".

Comment: Sorry! My fault!
The correct name is `JsHint Gutter`

Comment: Ok, mine works fine. Go into your Terminal and do "which node" to confirm your node path

Comment: My Terminal confirm the path... `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Hmm, that's weird! Quit Sublime Text and open it again.

Comment: Close SublimeText --> reboot the Mac --> open again SublimeText... The same error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, seems like you're gonna have to `node_path` to your nodes absolute path

Check this out  **[Oh noez, command not found!](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint#oh-noez-command-not-found)**

> If you get an error sh: node: command not found or similar, you don't have node in the right path. Try setting the absolute path to node in JSHint.sublime-settings.
>
> Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P in Linux/Windows/OS X
>   type jshint, select Set node Path
>   This means from: "node_path": "/usr/local/bin/node" change to "node_path": "/your/absolute/path/to/node"
>
> Simply using node without specifying a path sometimes doesn't work :(
>
> For example, on Linux the path could be in /home//.nvm//bin/node.

**Or just update to Sublime Text 3**

Comment: I try it before, but I couldn't found the absolute path... If I go to `use/local/bin` I find the the executable file and not a link, then I don't know where is it... Any idea?

Comment: Type $HOME in your Terminal and tell me what you get?

Comment: $HOME ==> -bash: /Users/TresMac: is a directory

Comment: Sorry, I dozed off and forgot. Is there a `.nvm` directory in your $HOME path i.e Users/TresMac?

Comment: Don't warry, it's ok! ;) 
No, I don't find any `.nvm` file or directory in /Users/TresMac

Comment: Hey @RikyTres, any luck yet?

Comment: Not yet... Any idea about the `.nvm` dir?

Comment: Nope, that's what the wiki suggested. Mine works fine so it's hard to diagnose

Comment: Should I have to find the ".nvm" directory or not?

Comment: you could try. If it does infact exist somewhere on you machine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45844/discussion-between-rikytres-and-dcodesmith)

Comment: I was having this issue with html-css-js.prettify.  In the end none of these issues worked for me and I had to comment out line 58-62 of HTMLPrettify.py so that the only line left would look up the path with the line...  

    node = settings.get("node_path")

I restarted SublimeText and it started working.